# Getting Exception: in android widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Hi I am trying to make an android widget. In this widget i am trying to update the value of my text view by calling a web service and getting the data from it and displaying it in the text view after a particular tie interval and i am getting an exception.

```
Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.newwidget.UpdateService@40ce9518withIntent{cmp=com.example.newwidget
/.UpdateService (has extras) }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Here is the code which i have tried,

Widget.java

```
  import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
  import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
  import android.content.ComponentName;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.widget.RemoteViews;
  import android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "OnUpdate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                Widget.class);
            int[] allWidgetIds =       appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
            Toast.makeText(context, "allWidgetIds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Build the intent to call the service
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
                UpdateService.class);
            Toast.makeText(context, "call UpdateService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);
            Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Update the widgets via the service
            context.startService(intent);
}

 }
```

UpdateService.java

```
   import java.io.IOException;

   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
   import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
   import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
   import android.content.ComponentName;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.IBinder;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.widget.RemoteViews;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class UpdateWidget extends Service {
    private RemoteViews views;
    private String url;
    private String strAPIRender;
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(null);
    private HttpResponse response;
    private HttpEntity httpEntity;


@Override
     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d("AppWidget.UpdateService", "onStart()");
    Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "Onstart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Build the widget update for today
    Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "Updateviews", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this);
        Log.d("WordWidget.UpdateService", "update built");

Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "buildupdate finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Push update for this widget to the home screen
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this, WidgetAppActivity.class);

        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

    Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "final update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);

    Log.d("WordWidget.UpdateService", "widget updated");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {
        // Pick out month names from resources
Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "buildupdate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
url = "http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR";

        grabURL(url);
Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "grabURL finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String result = strAPIRender;

views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_widget_app);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.update, result);
        return views;
    }
    public void grabURL(String url) {
Toast.makeText(UpdateWidget.this, "in grabURL method", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        Toast.makeText(null, "execute url", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
        //cancel(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            //cancel(true);
        }



        parseXml(Content);
    }



    public String parseXml(String content) {
        try {

            System.out.println(content);
            try {

                strAPIRender = XMLHandler.GetTagValue("double",content);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(" catch b");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" exception in parseXML");
        }
        return strAPIRender;


    }


}
```

Manifest file

```
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".Widget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="A Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.example.newwidget.UpdateService"></service>
   </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from UpdateService:

```
private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(null);
```

That "Dialog" doesn't appear (at quick glance of that class) to be used anywhere. If you do intend to use it you can't instantiate it like that (it needs a real Context). That should resolve the specific error you are asking about.

(Even if you fix that error, I'm not sure this code will work as expected. You might also want to consider, just for starters: remove all the toasts for debug purposes and use logging and logcat, and/or a debugger; don't use the main UI thread (which services also use by default) for network I/O (see IntentService for an easy way around that); don't do dialogs/alerts/toasts from a Service; and watch out for non-standard naming conventions like starting member variables in upper case, that makes the code difficult to follow (especially when it's not consistent, even if it doesn't follow the convention).)